# How set size on an EditText programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created an EditText programmatically. This EditText has one line and is added to a LinearLayout:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.select_options_option);
v = new EditText(context);
((EditText) v).setLines(1);
ll.addView(v);
```

My problem is that I can only type one character in this EditText. How can I set the width of an EditText, so that I can type in 3 or more charaters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding layout parameters to the linear layout before adding the TextView

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.select_options_option);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
v = new EditText(context);
((EditText) v).setLines(1);
ll.addView(v)
```

You can also add the `WRAP_CONTENT` in your xml file

Answer (score 3):

If you want your edittext to match the width of linearLayout

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
v.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

other wise if you want width to be equal to few character wide..

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEms(int)

```
v.setEms(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this too you can set EditText box height and width:

 LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(60,30); // Width , height or (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
 EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
 edittext.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```